# Will a page taking 2-3 mins to render cause a javascript 'taking too long' warning

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, timeout, render

I'm using the jQuery document ready method - `$(function()`

If the page takes too long to render (say 2mins+), will this be the reason for the page throwing a javascript taking too long to execute error/warning?

Comment: any insight on this javascript warning for IE welcomed.

Comment: OUt of curiosity what takes that long to render?

Comment: **Two minutes????** Do you seriously expect anybody to wait for that?

Comment: I would look into refactoring or redesigning your JavaScript. 2-3 minutes for a page load is so far beyond acceptability that it boggles the mind. Even if you don't get the warning, your potential users will run screaming.

Comment: someone else is looking into that... but when dealing with hundreds of records in a mailing system, containing many attachments, that is not shocking (not to say it can't be refactored to go even faster)

Comment: hey... stick to the question guys...

Comment: I'll take Igor's simple yes/no answer.

Comment: Well, @Brandon, how many websites do you commonly visit where the pages take 2 to 3 minutes to render?

Comment: Anything beyond 10 seconds better be amazing content or your users will leave.  As for the hundreds of records... Only load what you are displaying... And don't load any attachments until the user clicks on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `$(function(){})` will get called once the DOM is loaded - i.e. it doesn't keep running throughout the load process. Unless you are trying to do a long running synchronous task or stuck in a long loop, you shouldn't get that error.

Have a look at the CPU utilization. If it's high for the browser, it's a tell tale sign that there is an infinite loop somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

depends what you mean by "render".

if you are doing some intense processing in JS (like calculating the millionth prime number or something), the browser will display that message. if you are waiting for a resource to load and aren't grinding away on some script, you will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

No the document.ready only loads after the DOM is ready (i.e after the jquery core is loaded and ready to be used), so it will not throw any error, if a page takes 2-3 mins.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't - but test it.

To find out a little more, why not comment out your current load function, and put in a really simple load function, something like:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { alert("load firing");}
```

See if that makes a difference. Add stuff back in until it breaks.